# Handle youtube Ominauth 401 error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, youtube-api, omniauth

I am using omniauth youtube and google oauth2 gems for loggin in via youtube. This all works providing that the user has already created a youtube channel with the account they are trying to log in with.

When the user tries to log in without a youtube channel it errors out with the following message:

```
OAuth2::Error

    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>NoLinkedYouTubeAccount</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>NoLinkedYouTubeAccount</H1>
    <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

How could I handle this error so that the user is either sent to their youtube account where they can create their youtube channel and then be redirected back to the site with valid login credentials or to be sent back to a page which gives instructions on how to create a youtube channel and try again?

My code is as follows:

user.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.picture = auth.info.image
      user.save!
      end
    end
```

session_controller:

```
def create
      user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed in"
    end
```

routes

```
match 'auth/youtube/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = SessionsController.action(:oauth_failure)

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :youtube, YOUTUBE_KEY, YOUTUBE_SECRET, { access_type: 'online', approval_prompt: ''}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rescue_from` with something like :

```
rescue_from OAuth2::Error do |exception|
  redirect_to *your page you want to show with instructions*, :notice => "You must link a Youtube Channel"
end
```

Since adding a youtube channel is not part of the oauth cycle I do not think you can redirect to youtube, create one, and then bounce back to your site like the normal oauth authentication  so I would recommend giving the page with instructions with a link out to youtube for convenience.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

Comment: yes I think you are right Jason about redirecting to some instructions. This doesn't seem to be catching the exception, or if it is, the redirect isn't being performed. I have tried the code in the application controller & sessions controller but to no avail, is this where it is intended?